# How to RelativeLayout Align Center android

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="199dp"
        android:text="test" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="I want to align Center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my xml code.

I want to use layout_alignCenter="@+id/textView1" in TextView2.

But there is no alignCenter.

I think layout_centerVertical or centerinParent also useless.

Answer (score 12):

You wanted to show text view exact center of the screen....then use below modified code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="test" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="I want to align Center" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will definitely work for you. If there is any other requirement then explain in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap a the `RelativeLayout` in a `LinearLayout` and use `Space` elements:

```
<LinearLayout layout_width="0dp" layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="199dp"
            android:text="test" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="I want to align Center" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `Space` element will distribute empty space relatively between all `Space` elements, based on the layout weights.